# OpenAPI - can the parameter name value contain the ">" character?

Tags: openapi

I wan to use "**StartTime>**" as a parameter name. Can I use it in this form with ">" character at the end? 
 See example below

```
parameters:
      - description: Date after
        in: path
        name: StartTime>
        required: true
```